# Determine cause of prolonged "Calculating Formula..." notification

Tags: performance, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I recently took care of a working data sheet, with about 30 sheets of several thousand rows each sheet, with many cell colored for difference purpose. Most of the sheets only have raw data; a few working sheets have formulas / arrayformulas.

Here's a portion of my workbook:

[image]

In the red circle, you can see "Calculating formula....". This appears in my sheet very frequently, generally whenever I edit anything in any cell in any sheet.

I followed `https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/slow-google-sheets/` which doesn't help much to my situation. yeah, all 27 of them.

Now what I want to know is, is there any way to know just what is Google Sheets doing during the time that "Calculating formula..... " bar appear ? So I can see whichever function / formula is taking my precious time and then improve it.

Edit --

Since I cannot share the sheet, at least I'll share the working formula so that you guys can figure what is the sheets doing.

These are to be pasted to get the input data when working. Result will then be value pasted again to data sheet. These formulas are only in the working sheet:

v

```
=VLOOKUP($D2,TEMP!$A$1:$AT$99,23,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP($D2,TEMP!$A$1:$AT$99,11,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP($D2,TEMP!$A$1:$AT$99,16,FALSE)
=REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(VLOOKUP($D2,TEMP!$A$1:$AT$99,17,FALSE)), "^84", "0")
=VLOOKUP($D2,TEMP!$A$1:$AT$99,46,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP($D2,TEMP!$A$1:$AT$992,18,FALSE)

=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP($D3,TEMP!$G$1:$AS$492,9,FALSE), ",", VLOOKUP($D3,TEMP!$G$1:$AS$492,10,FALSE), ",", VLOOKUP($D3,TEMP!$G$1:$AS$492,7,FALSE))
=VLOOKUP($D3,TEMP!$G$1:$AS$492,6,FALSE)
=REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(VLOOKUP($D3,TEMP!$G$1:$AS$492,12,FALSE)), "^84", "")
```

This formula is used to set the status of the data -- only in working sheet:

v

```
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(E7:E10178,DonHangTraVe!A1:A20014,0)),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D7:D10178,DonHangTraVe!C1:C20014,0)),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D7:D10178,LAZ_Delivered!B1:B20000,0)),"","Received"),"Returned"), "Lost")))
```

This formula is placed in all of the data sheets. It will get the value in column E, turn them into links to their corresponding data in the server:

v

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(F:F)=1,"LINK", IF(LEN(E:E)=13, HYPERLINK("http://www._____________________?key=" & E:E, E:E), "")))
```

Those are the main formulas.

There is this one formula in a sheet, but it is turned off by placing a value one cell below. (Not me. I'm still trying to figure this out. Even the sheet maker unsure why he did that)

```
=ArrayFormula(trim(concatenate(filter(indirect("AQ1:AQ500")&" "&REGEXREPLACE(indirect("AR1:AR500"), "Dòng sản phẩm tương thích:.+",""), indirect("G1:G500")=G1)&CHAR(10))))
```

I turned the last formula down by setting an `if` with a switch (Benlcollins idea) but it doesn't help much.

After looking at all the formula, I think maybe the problem of my sheet lie in the arrayformula which adds the link.. I will tinker with it for now.

Still, the question remain.. is there any tool / script / addon that shows what google spreadsheet has been doing under these "Calculating formula..." bar ??

On the side note, this sheet is not using any script, in case you wonder if there's anything in onEdit(e) ..

Comment: I don't see sumproduct() calls on the list you linked. Have you checked for that? In my experience they are quite frequently a source of slow spreadsheets, in which case they can be replaced by faster mmult(). Other than that, I don't know of any general method of debugging GSheet performance.

Comment: Use of `INDIRECT` can often cause excessive recalculation as well. Consider sharing some examples of the actual formulas in use.

Comment: IMO, BenCollins is plain wrong. And I suggest that you use ARRAYFORMULAS for performance. Consider changing all dumb INDEX/MATCH formulas to ARRAYFORMULAS/VLOOKUP() or QUERY(). Delete all empty rows. If possible, Avoid all conditional formatting, unless essential.

Comment: @ttarchala no, there is no sum. This sheet is not about finance or anything related to number. Plain data to be stored to manage work in our shop. Therefore no sum, no count, if that matter.

Comment: @I'-'I yeah, I agree with you on the arrayformula part. I have experienced myself how quick the arrayformula with a sumif work in 500 rows in compare with 500 individual sumif(s). Well, among the methods, i find that #4 - using the Developer Tool looks interesting enough. I'm currently messing with it, I hope I can figure something out..

Comment: @tehhowch I edited my question, added the formulas that I'm working with so far. To be honest i'm surprised that the sheet only has so much formula, along with a few `if` here and there. That's why I have to come up with this question. What else is happening behind the scene ?